# Pyzipcode city lookup not working properly

Tags: django, zipcode

Trying to get the city from the zip code, so I installed the pyzipcode package. However, whenever I try to get the city I get the following error. The state, zipcode, lat/long work normally. I've tried numerous zipcodes and none of them seem to pull any city records.

```
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()
zipc=zcdb['90210']
zipc.city
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ZipCode' object has no attribute 'city'
```

The documentation for the package uses 'city' as an example: https://pypi.org/project/pyzipcode/.

Comment: The documentation example uses zip code in integer format, like `zcdb[54115]`.  Why are you using string format `zcdb['90210']`?

Comment: I get the same error: >>> z=zcdb[94010]
>>> z.city
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ZipCode' object has no attribute 'city'

Comment: Have you tried `dir(z)` to see what attributes the object does have?

Comment: Thank you. It's z.place is analogous to z.city for this package.